# Calculate the sum under gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm

I have a question: How can I calculate

$$\sum_{i=1\atop \gcd(i,75)=1}^{75} i=?$$

Comment: Do the sum without the gcd condition. Then think about multiples of 3, multiples of 5, and inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, they come in pairs: if $\gcd(i,75)=1$, then so is $\gcd(75-i,75)$. Obviously, sum of the numbers in each pair is 75; as for the number of pairs, it is half the number of numbers less than 75 and [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime) to it, which is given by the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).